# Select element by ID from variable

Tags: jquery

How can I select an input when the name is on a variable? in this case the variable is idThis = "nico"

```
  <input name="man-news" />
  <input id="nico" name="milkman" />
  <input name="letterman2" />
  <input name="newmilk" />

<script>
    var idThis = "nico";    
    $('input[id=idThis ]').val('has man in it!');

</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ - No problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can either construct a selector string:

```
$('#' + idThis)
```

Or wrap a native DOM method:

```
$(document.getElementById(idThis))
```

The second one works for any id, while the first one will break if the id has spaces or dots in it.

Answer (score 0):

use `#id` to select an element by its id:

```
<script>
    var idThis = "nico";    
    $('input#'+idThis).val('has man in it!');
</script>
```

or just:

```
<script>
    var idThis = "nico";    
    $('#'+idThis).val('has man in it!');
</script>
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9x4b9/1/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't match the code in your answer here (which is wrong).

Comment: @j08691: Sorry, I didn't realize there is need to copy all four buttons, but I updated it for you :-) And I overlooked the `id` is a variable, thanks for bringing that to my attention.