# How is it possible to run a jQuery function with an variable instead of an id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how is it possible to run a jQuery function like this:

```
$('#do here the variable').trigger('click');
```

with a variable which contains the id as a string like:
`var demoid = "idx";`

So how should the correct syntax been written?

A try of me was this:

```
function doItLikeAClick(){
var demoid = "idx";
$(demoid).trigger('click');}
```

But this does not work.
JavaScript does stopp.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17002725/2864740

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select element by ID from variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002715/select-element-by-id-from-variable)

Comment: Guys, take it easy on the guy, maybe this is his first time to use jquery and he doesn't know how to use a search engine.

Comment: Sorry, yes it was a duplicate of this: stackoverflow.com/a/17002725/2864740 –  user2864740 yesterday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

```
$('#' + demoid).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 3):

The obvious solution ( `$('#' + demoid)` ) is only correct for some id. It wouldn't work, for example, with this correct id : `"a:b"`.

You should only use it when you know that your id complies with jquery selector parsing rules (a standard looking id does).

The good (and faster) reliable way is

```
$(document.getElementById(demoid))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var demoid = "idx";
$('#'+demoid).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var demoid = $('#idx');

demoid.trigger('click');
```